# Insert list data into DB2 in python

Tags: python, sql, db2

I have this problem with inserting a list of tuple into a database in DB2 in python

my previous task was create a variable that contain all the data

but I couldn't insert that data into data warehouse

this my code in previous task

```
def get_latest_records(rowid):
    MySQL_query = "SELECT * FROM sales_data WHERE rowid > %s"
    cursor.execute(MySQL_query, (rowid,))
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    return result
    
new_records = get_latest_records(last_row_id)
print("New rows on staging datawarehouse = ", len(new_records))
print(type(new_records))
print(new_records[0:2])
```

[output showing sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTwYK.jpg)

Sow i have a variable contain list of data I try to insert that data into DB2 Warehouse

I want every tuple to insert to database as row
(12290, 6715, 80213, 1)

the number the record 12290 insert into rowid in database

and 6715 insert to product_id

80213 insert to customer_id

1 insert to quantity

and this is database schema

[database schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyQMC.jpg)

I try this code

```
def insert_records(records):
    Db2_Insert = "INSERT INTO SALES_DATA VALUES(?,?,?,?);"
    prepare = ibm_db.prepare(conn, Db2_Insert)
    ibm_db.execute(prepare, (records,))
     

insert_records(new_records)
print("New rows inserted into production datawarehouse = ", len(new_records))
```

Not working
[exception error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYNbQ.jpg)

thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

Avoid building a nested iterable object. Because `records` is a list, there is no need to wrap it in a tuple. The params you attempt to bind, `(records,)` is a one-item tuple of a list object (where that list carries potentially 4 values).

Therefore, simply pass the list directly in `params` argument. Scalars, not iterables, are what you want to avoid in [**`ibm_db.execute`**](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/9.7?topic=statements-preparing-executing-sql-variable-input):

```py
def insert_records(records):
    Db2_Insert = "INSERT INTO SALES_DATA VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?);"
    prepare = ibm_db.prepare(conn, Db2_Insert)
    ibm_db.execute(prepare, records)
```